# how to position a button in HBox - JAVAFx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am new to JAVAfx, i trying to code a web browser. The problem i am facing is :- i want to place the button present on the **Bottom left of the screen to the bottom right.**

I am trying this code but it is not working. Somebody please help

```
Button Developer = new Button(); 
Developer.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
```

here is the screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RTpr.png

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set the alignment on the `HBox` instead of the `Button` itself.

```
Button developer = new Button(); 

HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
hbox.getChildren().add(developer);
```

Comment: So, that means for positioning every button on a HBox i have to make a new hbox for placing it ?

Comment: You can either create another `HBox` or if you want to position them on different sides a `BorderPane` or `AnchorPane` may be a better option but im far away from being an expert in jfx either.